# React player vimeo pause

Tags: reactjs, react-player

my react player suddenly does not call the onPause callback anymore. I tried  https://cookpete.com/react-player/ here and the same problem persists.
When you are playing a video and pause it, the onPause callback is not being called when you are using vimeo. Strangely, it works with youtube video though. It just happened out of the blue and I assume it is vimeos error (not on the player itself, since I did not update it, I think)
Can anybody confirm/fix this error?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, with no change on my end.
Was an issue with vimeo...